# Error con ImagePicker en swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

Estoy tratando de obtener una imagen de la camara o de la libreria. La imagen la puedo coger, el problema es que no la guarda.

He puesto `print` de test pero tampoco me llega a la funcion delegada de guardar la imagen.

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

//A esta funcion no llega porque no me muestra el print
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.imageView.image = image

    print("TEST")

    self.imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func cogerImagen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.imagePicker.isEditing = true
    self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Fíjate si tu *view controller* implementa el protocolo `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Comment: Si, tengo estos: `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate` porque sino me dadba error @MarcosCrispino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que debes setear el delegado de una de estas dos maneras:

Opción 1:

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController() {
    didSet {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Opción 2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: Lo he puesto asi, pero me sigue sin funcionar @mhergon

Comment: Pues es muy raro... ten en cuenta que has de añadir también el `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Comment: Sii, tengo ese y `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. El caso esque cuando estaba en `swift 2` me funcionaba, pero al pasar a `swift 3` ya no me funciona @mhergon

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los problemas lo he corregido con la solucion de @mhergon

Pero otro problema era que han cambiado los parámetros de la función. La solución es:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
```